# Why functions return true and false?

Tags: c#

This code will return **true**:

```
private bool SimpleComparison()
{
    return new byte() == new byte();
}
```

This code will return **false**:

```
private bool AnotherSimpleComparison()
{
    return new byte[0] == new byte[0];
}
```

Can't understand, why? As I understand, in the second case it is differend addresses?
And what about first case?

Comment: All of the answers on the duplicate are wrong; this has nothing to do with whether or not the types in question are value types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload of the `==` operator in which both operands are of type `byte` and it is implemented to compare the value of each byte; in this case you have two zero bytes, and they are equal.

The `==` operator isn't overloaded for arrays, so the overload having two `object` operands is used in the second case, and its implementation compares the references to the two objects.  The reference to the two arrays are different.